LaTeX Error: Loading a class or package in a group – Need help resolving
I’m working on a LaTeX project, and I keep encountering the following error:
LaTeX Error: Loading a class or package in a group.

I’ve checked my code, but I’m not able to locate where exactly the error is being triggered. From my understanding, this error typically occurs when trying to load a class or package inside a group.
Could someone help me identify what might be causing this issue? Below is the relevant part of my code.
Thanks in advance for your assistance!
\documentclass[12pt,fleqn,english,round]{report}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{titlesec}

% Define a custom chapternew format
\titleformat{\chapternew}[display]
  {\normalfont\Huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[unicode=true,pdfusetitle,
 bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=false,bookmarksopen=false,
breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 0},pdfborderstyle={},colorlinks=false]
 {hyperref}

\geometry{verbose,tmargin=2.5cm,bmargin=2.5cm,lmargin=2.5cm,rmargin=2.5cm}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage{arabtex}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setlength{\parskip}{\medskipamount}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{babel}
\makeatletter
\addto\extrasfrench{%
   \providecommand{\og}{\leavevmode\flqq~}%
   \providecommand{\fg}{\ifdim\lastskip>\z@\unskip\fi~\frqq}%
}
\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl} 
%\makenomenclature 
%\renewcommand{\nomname}{Acronyms}

%\makeatother
\usepackage{array}
%\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
%\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=numeric,
sorting=none
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage{afterpage}
\newcommand\myemptypage{
    \null
    %\thispagestyle{empty}
    %\addtocounter{page}{-1}
    \newpage
    }


\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
%% Because html converters don't know tabularnewline
\providecommand{\tabularnewline}{\\}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
%\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{backref=true,isbn=false}
%\setmainfont[Scale=1.05]{EB Garamond} % for use with XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX; download from bitbucket.org/georgd/eb-garamond
%Options: Sonny, Lenny, Glenn, Conny, Rejne, Bjarne, Bjornstrup
\usepackage{lipsum} % Package for generating random text
\usepackage[Glenn]{fncychap}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{3pt}
\AtBeginDocument{
  \def\labelitemi{\normalfont\bfseries{--}}
  \def\labelitemii{\(\circ\)}
}
\makeatother
\newenvironment{dedication}
  {%\clearpage           % we want a new page          %% I commented this
   \thispagestyle{empty}% no header and footer
   \vspace*{\stretch{1}}% some space at the top
   \itshape             % the text is in italics
   \raggedleft          % flush to the right margin
  }
  {\par % end the paragraph
   \vspace{\stretch{3}} % space at bottom is three times that at the top
   \clearpage           % finish off the page
  }
\floatstyle{ruled}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
% \usepackage{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
% added by me
\usepackage{rotating}
% \usepackage{algorithmic}

\begin{document}
\begin{onehalfspace}
\thispagestyle{empty} 
\end{onehalfspace}
\begin{onehalfspace}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=14cm,height=1.8cm]{chapters/images/logothese.pdf}
\par\end{center}
\end{onehalfspace}

\begin{center}
\textbf{\huge{}Doctoral Thesis}{\Huge\par}
\par\end{center}

\begin{center}
\textit{\large{}Opérée au sein de \textbf{School} (University)}{\LARGE\par}
\par\end{center}

\begin{center}
\textbf{\large{} Spécialité : Computer }{\huge\par}
\par\end{center}

\begin{center}
{\large{} Par }{\par}
{\Large{} \textbf{Firstname Lastname} }{\huge\par}
\par\end{center}
\vspace{0.5cm}
\begin{center}
\hrule
\vspace{0.75cm}
\textbf{\LARGE{}Métaheuristiques hybrides et méthodes d'apprentissage}{\LARGE\par}
\vspace{1cm}
\hrule

%\textit{\LARGE{}Approches de gestion autonomique de la QoS au niveau  middleware dans le système de communication dans IoT}{\LARGE\par}

\par\end{center}

\vspace{10.5cm}



\pagenumbering{roman}
\input{chapters/englishresume}
\input{chapters/frenchresume}
%\input{Chapters/FrenshResume}
%\input{Chapters/Dedicace}
%\input{Chapters/Remerciement}
%\begin{onehalfspace}

\tableofcontents{}

%\pagenumbering{roman}%numérotation avec les chiffres romains
 %début de la numérotation est 1.
\listoftables
\listoffigures
\listofalgorithms
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Algorithms}
%\end{onehalfspace}
%\printnomenclature

%\nomenclature{AE}{Entité d'application (Application Entity)}
% numérotation avec les chiffres arabe

 % début de la numérotation est 1.
         
        \input{chapters/introduction}
        \input{chapters/chapter1}
        \input{chapters/chapter2}
        \input{chapters/chapter3}
        \input{chapters/conclusion}

%\appendix
%\input{Chapters/long-frensh-resume}
    %-----------------Fin Zone 5: fin de la numÃ©rotation---------------------
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\printbibliography

\end {document}


Seems to be an issue with arabtex. If you don't need it, don't load it. If you need it, try to eliminate it using a UTF8 engine, e.g., LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX and babel support for Arabic. See the manual for more information.

BTW: It was very easy to identify arabtex as problem. I've just started from the beginning and commented the first package, which is less usual. You should always try to minimize your preamble doing similar. Even if you don't find the source of your problem, already minimized code would help us to help you.

it is easy to find the issue: copy your preamble in a new document, add \begin{document}blub\end{document}. And then start to remove lines. Generally it would be a good idea to clean up your preamble. E.g. it doesn't make sense to load mathptmx and mathpazo and graphicx three times.

Thank you for the helpful response! I tested the code by removing the arabtex package, and it resolved the issue.
